# Django annotate + SUM how to get all entries

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-database-functions

My models

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    machineName = models.CharField(verbose_name="Machine Name", max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)


class SalesReport(models.Model):
    machine = models.ForeignKey(Machine, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    deviceDate = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    serverDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    totalPrice = models.FloatField()
```

I have 3 machines, I wanted to get the total sales from each machines for the last 7 days.

my query is

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Value as V
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

SalesReport.objects.values("serverDate__date", "machine__machineName").annotate(
...                 sales=Coalesce(Sum("totalPrice"),V(0))).filter(
...                                                 serverDate__gte=week_start,
...                                                 serverDate__lte=week_end)
```

Which gives the following result,

```
[{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 22), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__1', 'sales': 15.0},
 {'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 28), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__1', 'sales': 145.0},
 {'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 28), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__2', 'sales': 270.0},
 {'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 28), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__3', 'sales': 255.0}]
```

What i am trying to get is

```
[{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 22), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__1', 'sales': 15.0},
{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 22), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__2', 'sales': 0.0},
{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 22), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__3', 'sales': 0.0},
{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 28), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__1', 'sales': 145.0},
{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 28), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__2', 'sales': 270.0},
{'serverDate__date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 28), 'machine__machineName': 'machine__3', 'sales': 255.0}]
```

I am trying to do it with Coalesce, but i'm getting it wrong .

*I'm using mysql as db. a db specific query is also fine .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is more SQL question I add a more specific answer

```sql
SELECT m.machineName, s.price
FROM machine m LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT machine_id id, sum(totalPrice) price
FROM salesreport
WHERE serverDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and curdate()
GROUP BY by machine_id) s on m.id = s.id
```

If you want the serverDate as outpout you have to apply an aggregate function (Max, Min) since it is located in your SalesReport table.

It depends what serverDate stands for. If it is the date when you bought the machine then it should be in machine table and it can be selected directly from machine table (and the WHERE BETWEEN clause must exist the sub-select and also apply on machine table). If it is a salesDate then it has to be in SalesReport and you must apply an aggregate function on it. ie: You can have potentially 7 dates over a week...

```sql
SELECT m.machineName, s.MaxserverDate, s.price
FROM machine m LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT machine_id id, max(serverDate) MaxserverDate, sum(totalPrice) price
FROM salesreport
WHERE serverDate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) and curdate()
GROUP BY by machine_id) s on m.id = s.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you don't have any sales for some dates. It is more a DB specific issue than a django ORM one. I would suggest to use [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/) with a left outer join on your machine table => take all the machine and list sales when present.

```py
machine = Machine.objects.raw('''
    SELECT machine.id, machine.name, sales.sid FROM app_machinelist as machine
    LEFT JOIN (select sales_id as sid
                 from app_sales
                where profile_id = {0}) sales
    ON sales.sid = machine.id
    ORDER BY machine.name ASC
    '''.format(myuser.id))
```

This example works but for security reason, it is better to pass your parameters through a dictionary

```py
machine = Machine.objects.raw(mysql, params)
```

Where

```py
params = {'profile_id': pk, 'startdate': startdate, 'enddate': enddate}

mysql = '''
    SELECT machine.id, machine.name, sales.sid FROM app_machinelist as machine
    LEFT JOIN (select sales_id as sid
                 from app_sales
                where profile_id = %(profile_id)s) sales
    ON sales.sid = machine.id
    ORDER BY machine.name ASC
    '''
```

Comment: Moreover, to get your last 7 days you could perform a date difference between Today and serverDate and keep records when this difference is greater than 8

Comment: What I need is the sum of total sales happened in each machines for a given date . That I already accomplished here . But if  there is no sale in a machine , it should also be shown with sales as 0.